# I have two lists Found Missed Element count and Founded Element Count in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, sorting

Given two lists A and B:

```
A={6,16,22}
B={6,7,8,22,24,25}
```

I want to get:

```
1. the number of items that appear in both lists. (E.g. "2", because 6 and 22 from `A` are also in `B`.)
 2. the number of items that are in `A` but not in `B`. (E.g. "1", because 16 is in `A` but not in `B`)
 3.The number of items count adjacent numbers as 1 (E.g, A 6 is there B 6,7,8 is there so 6,7,8 count as 1 )
```

Comment: mishit and truehit? I don't understand. You want to get the count of different elements A from B ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "missed element counts" but I strongly suspect that LINQ makes this trivail, e.g. `int count = A.Except(B).Count();` or similar.

Comment: What would you expect the result to be?

Comment: A is count That is While Comapring A with B I want count of A's element  which is not in B

Comment: @munisamy: show sample data, a desired result and what you've tried to achieve that result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var aNotInB = a.Except(b);
int aNotInBCount = aNotInB.Count(); // 1 because 16 is not in second list
var aInB = a.Intersect(b);
int aInBCount = aInB.Count();       // 2 because 6,22 are in second list
```

Comment: Thanks it works.I have another question I need count if A is element 6 is there and B 6,7,8 is there count 6,7,8 as one how do i do?

Comment: @munisamy: what is the rule for counting  6,7,8 as one?

Comment: adjacent values of "6". the values i may get is one of the following 
1. 6,7,8
2. 5,6,7
3. 4,5,6

whatever above sequence i am getting, i need to get the count as 1

Comment: @munisamy: you should ask one question  for one requirement.   So don't add new requirements to your list. You should also show your effort, otherwise people will think that you're just asking for code. Apart from that, it's not clear why it's one or when it's two since your sample data is not meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

What u want is here:

```
A.Except(B).Count();
```